# Javascript rating - result to same line

Tags: javascript, rating

How can I get the result 1-5 in the same line, while hovering on circles?

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/3xLnxahq/

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
        <ul id="rating">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like the list items to appear on the same line?

Comment: Please see the jsfiddle.....while hovering on the circles the results (1 2 3 4 5) coming separate line....how its come in the same line?

Comment: Down-voting because of a language barrier is absurd. The Fiddle makes clear what the issue is.

Comment: The question is completely unclear and the fiddle didn't make it easier for me...

Comment: I don't know what other conclusion one could come to looking at the fiddle and repeatedly reading the words "same line." What other info was needed to answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a clear:left in the ratinginfo div. This means no other floating elements can be to the left of it, and so it's appearing as a sort of new line. Replace it with a float left declaration.

Also the p tag is adding paragraph space which disrupts the float left declaration. Change the p tag to a div tag.

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3L9rhqt0/

New CSS:

```
#ratinginfo {float:left; width:50px; margin-left:0px; }
```

The new js:

```
    // Add the text to the rating info box
    $("<div />")
        .html($(this).html())
        .appendTo(ratingInfobox);
```

Comment: Cheers! Good luck with your project.